# Merge tag [conversation] with tag [conversations]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Both tags [conversation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversation) and [conversations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversations) refer to the same subject and thus should be merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems a sensible proposal. Tags now merged.